# What's the fastest way to find a value that is not in an SQL database table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a SQL Server database table `Organisation` containing a `smallint` column `iCompanyID` (ignore the naming convention, it dates back 12 years) that is neither an identity nor indexed, but must be unique; what is the fastest way to find a new value that does not already exist in the table?

The catch is that I want this to remain fast as the range of possible values is used up. In reality I don't expect there to be more than a few hundred values used so either of my methods will perform well enough so I'm asking out of pure interest.

I have two methods, one generating a random number, then checking if it exists in the table; if not it tries another. This method may never complete as the values are used up so is not a good answer.

```
DECLARE @companyId SMALLINT
DECLARE @value INT

WHILE @companyId IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Organisation WHERE iCompanyID = @companyId)
BEGIN
    SET @value = FLOOR(65535 * RAND(DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) * 100000 + DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) * 1000 + DATEPART(ms, GETDATE())) + 1)
    IF @value > 32767
        SET @companyId = @value - 65536
    ELSE
        SET @companyId = @value
END

SELECT @companyId [Available ID]
```

The other method is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5301166/1535) and generates a list of all possible values. This is outer joined to the table and the first possible value with a null match in the table is returned. Testing has shown that this also becomes very slow as values are used up, but it should at least complete if there is even one available value.

```
WITH q AS
(
  SELECT firstId, lastId FROM (SELECT -32768 firstId, 32767 lastId) r
        UNION ALL
  SELECT  firstId + 1, lastId FROM q WHERE firstId < lastId
)
SELECT  TOP 1 q.firstId [Available ID]
FROM    q LEFT JOIN dbo.Organisation o ON q.firstId = o.iCompanyID
WHERE   o.iCompanyID IS NULL
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I'm sure someone smarter than myself could find a way of doing this that doesn't slow down as the available values decrease and I would be interested to see other possible methods.

Please, no suggestions to add indices to the table; it's methods within the current constraints I'm interested in.

Comment: My first thought was: Whatever you do, you need an index on this column to make the search process faster. Whenever the column is part of a `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause you'll be much happier if you have an index.

Comment: So, `iCompanyID` is not an IDENTITY and it's not indexed.  Does it have a UNIQUE constraint?  (I know, that would implicitly create an index on the column, but you didn't specify explicit vs implicit for "not indexed").  Can you add a UNIQUE constraint?  Or is that outside of your control?

Comment: Are you saying selecting the maximum value in the table and adding 1 is not acceptable?

Comment: Tim, the table contains legacy data with random IDs. This means that the maximum value could be taken while there are many lower values available.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way would be to use `ROW_NUMBER` to find the first index that is unused but I have no idea whether it's faster than your methods. Ultimately, like the other methods, it still has to sort the data and iterate it, so unless you can index or denormalise this data, I can't see massive performance gains.

```
SELECT TOP 1 newId FROM 
(
   SELECT newId=(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY iCompanyId)) - 1, iCompanyId FROM Organisation
   GROUP BY iCompanyId
) rownums 
WHERE newId <> iCompanyId
```